# Filtering a column with another columns values

Tags: excel, filter, filtering, advanced-filter

I assume this is related to advanced filter, but I could not succeed until now with it.

I have 2 Columns, Column A has 2000 number values, Column B has 6000 number values. I want to filter Column B with Columns A values (means I need to set 2000 filters).

I know how to filter single or multiple values, as it is easy by selecting checkboxes, but since it is 2000 numbers to filter, I can not do this manually.

How can I filter Column B with the whole Column A values?

Comment: Please [read this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495) about asking for urgency from volunteers.

Answer (score 4):

Add this formula to column C:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)
```

And scroll it to the end of column B.

Now filter column C for values greater than 0.

Comment: this unofortunately did not help, it gives an error

Comment: What kind of error? Did you try setting range to $A$1:$A$2000, given that you said column A has 2000 values.